# Wrap table to multi columns in RDLC

Tags: report, rdlc, tabular

[image]

A dynamic list (name, page number) need to be generated to RDLC report. But I need to wrap it to three columns like this. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 8):

I would set up a matrix like this:

[image]

The Row Group is based on the expression:

```
=Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing) / 3)
```

The Column Group is based on the expression:

```
=(RowNumber(Nothing) - 1) Mod 3
```

i.e. we're grouping based on the row number of each row.

This gives the required results for your data:

[image]

Comment: Did you have any luck with this suggestion?

Comment: this works like a charm, thank you so much, I had the same issue as the OP and now it's fixed. Your answer should be accepted by the OP.

Comment: this seems to almost work except that the items go to the right first instead of down first