# RDLC Reporting with multiple Columns

Tags: report, rdlc

I'm using VS2008 and VS2013 in order to create some small client reports for our customers. However, everything I try to do to make this work is getting me nowhere, and half the tutorials I see either don't apply anymore, or apply differently to either VS2008, VS2010, or VS2013.

What I'm trying to accomplish seems easy in concept. The page is to have 3 columns, with a table repeating through the columns. The table had three columns, a customer number, a delivery amount, and then a blank column.

However, everything I try either:
A) Causes repeating data.
B) Creates one column that continues onto the next pages without repeating it's header.
C) Simply causes a code error.

I've looked into various things, and I've seen a few get extremely close ([Wrap table to multi columns in RDLC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824449/wrap-table-to-multi-columns-in-rdlc)), however, I'm unable to replicate what they're doing in my versions because usually just one of the things they're doing, I don't seem to have access to. (In the link above, try as I might, I can't get the group to span two columns like his picture showed)

Is there something extra I need to download in order to get this working?

Any help would be appreciated (or a recommendation to another .net report designer).

Answer (score 3):

You can set `Columns` and `ColumnSpacing` properties of your report:

1. display `Property` window
2. click on `Report` (grey area outside your page)
3. find and set `Columns` properties

In VS2008 you have to click on `Report Body` to set the `Columns` properties.

Then simply put your 3-columns `Tablix` in the `Column 1`.

This method doesn't optimize report space (as the one in your link): it fills a column and then pass to the next.

Please note that to see the desired output you need to preview/print/export the report; normal view only display one column.