# Continue loading rows into next column RDLC

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, rdlc

I have a problem for days with a report that I have to make.

I have a dataset (datatable) with one column and it has 94 rows of data, and I want to load this data into a tablix of a 12-column rdlc report, my question is:

How can I load up to 8 rows and then it continues to load in the next column, do I have to generate dynamic columns?

I found that I can use an array combined with a list, to load up to 12 columns and then jump to the next line, but this doesn't work for me, because it loads the data from left to right and I need it to load the data from top to bottom, for example

[image: Example]

Thanks

Comment: See following which is tabulating rows and you want columns.  So reverse the MOD and the DIVIDE : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824449/wrap-table-to-multi-columns-in-rdlc

Comment: I will see if this answer helps me, thanks for answering

Comment: You can often brute-force presentation problems like this by building a dataset or list of objects in code, to use as the data source for the report, then populating this from the original dataset pulled from the db, including code to perform any processing or re-arrangement of layout you require.

Comment: Thanks!, jdweng's answer is correct, I have to invest MOD and DIVIDE in the answer that was raised in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824449/wrap-table-to-multi-columns-in-rdlc